# Auto-refreshing content loaded in with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a small script that loads in the last song I listened to from last.fm with jQuery, as seen below:

```
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=paul_r_schaefer&api_key=0f680404e39c821cac34008cc4d803db&format=json', function(data) {
var song = $(".song"), artistVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"], trackVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].name;
song.append(artistVal + " \u2014 " + trackVal); });
```

Is there any way I can make it remove what it already appended to the `<span class="song"></span>` and load again? For the life of me, I can't figure out a way that doesn't duplicate the song.

EDIT: This works, however, it has a delay when it first loads. Is there a way I can get it to run once, then refresh every 3 seconds?

```
function listens() {
    $.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=paul_r_schaefer&api_key=0f680404e39c821cac34008cc4d803db&format=json', function(data) {
        var song = $(".song"), artistVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"], trackVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].name;
        song.html(artistVal + " \u2014 " + trackVal);
    });
}
setInterval(listens, 3000);
```

EDIT 2: This gets rid of the lag, just is there a way I can slim this down?

```
listens();
function listens() {
    $.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=paul_r_schaefer&api_key=0f680404e39c821cac34008cc4d803db&format=json', function(data) {
        var song = $(".song"), artistVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"], trackVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].name;
        song.html(artistVal + " \u2014 " + trackVal);
    });
}
setInterval(listens, 3000);
```

Comment: I think you forgot to finish your question.  You haven't asked anything.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter before I was finished haha

Comment: It happens, just wanted to make sure you were aware ;)

Comment: So, you only want to append when it's a new song (one that isn't already appended)?

Comment: Yeah, I just want it to check the server for any new song, and update it if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that jQuery's `.append()` well, *appends*. It appends, or adds, onto what is the existing HTML in the element. You want to replace the element's HTML entirely, so your approach should be something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=paul_r_schaefer&api_key=0f680404e39c821cac34008cc4d803db&format=json', function(data) {
var song = $(".song"), artistVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"], trackVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].name;
song.html(artistVal + " \u2014 " + trackVal); });
```

Check out [$.html(htmlString)](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

> **From the jQuery API:**
>
> *Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.*

Answer (score 0):

This works good enough for me.

```
listens();
function listens() {
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=paul_r_schaefer&api_key=0f680404e39c821cac34008cc4d803db&format=json', function(data) {
    var song = $(".song"), artistVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"], trackVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].name;
    song.html(artistVal + " \u2014 " + trackVal);
});
}
setInterval(listens, 2000);
```